# No AA support in Godot 3.1?

Tags: godot, antialiasing, post-processing

I'm using Godot 3.1.1 and just realized that there is no available AA options. According to some post, Godot 2 supports FXAA, but some reason it's took out from 3. So I try to get FXAA for Godot 3.1, but couldn't find any.

I don't want to publish my game without Anti Aliasing. Is there a way to apply FXAA in Godot 3.1.1 which using GLES3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Still Godot 3.1 doesn't support FXAA, however there are some user implemented version.

If you are using GLES3, use this:
https://gist.github.com/cart/7d2da58eb28c75c0952787f29f3e562f

If you are using GLES2, use this:
https://github.com/atomius0/Godot-3.1-FXAA-Shader/blob/master/project/fxaa/fxaa.shader

Steps to apply FXAA:

1. Create ColorRect Node
2. Set Layout to "Full Rect" so that it covers whole screen
3. Create new Shader Material and assign shader script in your ColorRect node you just 
   created.
4. Run the game.

Tested with Godot 3.1.1 with GLES3 in 3D scene.